# Degree of the projection of a projective variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $X\subseteq\mathbb{P}^n\times\mathbb{P}^m\subseteq \mathbb P^{(n+1)(m+1)-1}$ be a projective variety of dimension $p$ and degree $d$ defined over an algebraically closed field $k$, where $\mathbb{P}^n\times\mathbb{P}^m\subseteq \mathbb P^{(n+1)(m+1)-1}$ via the Segre embedding. Let $X'\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ be the projection of $X$ on $\mathbb{P}^n$, which we will assume having dimension equal to that of $X$. What can we say about the degree $d'$ of $X'$? Is there some formula linking the degrees $d$ and $d'$. Since an analytical charcaterization is also good for my purposes, feel free to assume $k=\mathbb C$.

Comment: What do you mean by degree $d$? With respect to what ample line bundle?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn I mean the classical one: Number of points in the intersection of $X$ with $p$-hyperplanes in general position.

Comment: Yes, but hyperplanes of which ample line bundle?

Comment: @VincenzoZaccaro: Your question is ill-posed. Without specifying more details, there is no such thing as a hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^m$. Subvarieties such as $X$ come with bidegrees, not degrees.

Comment: Hi Vincenzo: In more down-to-earth terms, the degree of a projective variety depends on the  projective space where the variety is embedded. In your case, the variety $X$ could be embedded via de Segre map, for example.

Comment: You are absolutely  right guys (I'm sorry). My bad! I was implicitely embedding the product $\mathbb P^n\times \mathbb P^m$ in $\mathbb P^N$ via the Segre embedding.

Comment: Let $h_1,h_2$ be the hyperplane class in $CH^1(\mathbb{P}^n)$ and $CH^1(\mathbb{P}^m)$, and $q_1,q_2$ the two projections. Then  $d=(q_1^*h_1+q_2^*h_2)^p$, and $d'=q_1^*h_1^p$. Obviously you cannot say more than $d'\leq d$.

Comment: One can say more if $X$ is irreducible. Would you be willing to add that hypothesis? Or do you need more general results, for possibly reducible varieties?

Comment: @ZachTeitler it's ok also adding that assumption :)

Answer (score 2):

As abx says in his comment, all you can say is $d' \le d$. Here are some explicit examples with $m = 2$ and $n = 1$.

(1) To see that $d'$ can be arbitrarily smaller than $d$, fix a line $L \subseteq \mathbb{P}^2$ and set $X = L \times S$, where $S \subseteq \mathbb{P}^1$ is a finite set of points.  Then $X$ has degree $\lvert S\rvert$ while has $X' = L$ has degree 1.

(2) To see that we can also have $d' = d$, take a degree $d$ curve $C \subseteq \mathbb{P}^2$ and set $X = C \times \{*\}$ for some point $* \in \mathbb{P}^1$.  Then $X$ has degree $d$, and $X' = C$ also has degree $d$.